# Cannot execute shell script without command line manual classpath update first

Tags: shell, jar, cron, classpath

I hope this is fairly simple but I'm struggling to get this to work.

I have a java package which I want to execute using a shell script command...

```
/jdk1.7.0/bin/java .path.to.classname.ClassToExecute >> /var/log/output.log
```

...so essentially...

```
./SCRIPT_NAME
```

...should run the above from the command line.

The problem is there is a classpath update needed every time first from the command line to enable the session to see a particular JAR...

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jar/file/lib/JAR_NAME.jar:.
```

If I don't put this line in first the shell script will not execute throwing errors of NoClassDefFoundError relating to the JAR I need to add manually.

Can anyone tell me where I need to edit this classpath update so that it's ALWAYS available to the script and also to the cron as ultimately I want to call it from the cron?

Thanks,
ForestSDMC

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script should look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jar/file/lib/JAR_NAME.jar:. 
/jdk1.7.0/bin/java .path.to.classname.ClassToExecute >> /var/log/output.log
```

You also need to change the permissions of the script so that it is executable

```
chmod 700 SCRIPT_NAME
```

700 = owner can only execute the script
770 = owner and members of a group can run the script
777 = everyone who has access to the server can run the script.

Noticed that you want to run this from cron.  You need to source your .profile either from the crontab entry or from within the script.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer and works fine so hopefully others will find this useful...

You can dynamically generate the classpath variable within the shell script and then apply it as an attribute to the java command line execution.  Like this...

```
THE_CLASSPATH=
for i in `ls /path/to/the/JARS/lib/*.jar`
do
  THE_CLASSPATH=${THE_CLASSPATH}:${i}
done

/usr/bin/java -cp ".:${THE_CLASSPATH}" path.to.the.class.ClassName >> /var/log/logfile.log
```